# Removing reciprocal/similar records using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, delete-row

I have a table with names, some of which are shorthand for others and some which are similar but are not. For instance `Michael` and `Mike` are reciprocal, yet `Uncle Michael` is not. I ran a script to get the either one- or two-way matching e.g.

```
Michael | Mike
Mike | Michael
```

yet only

```
Michael | Uncle Michael
```

which indicates they are not matching pairs.

I'm trying to use that to then remove the shorter matching term (e.g. `Mike`).

I have a [SqlFiddle demonstrating this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee637/1), I can get as far as finding only the matching pairs but am unsure how to now do a `Delete t1` to delete the shorter of the found record from all of the matching pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some insight from db server's perspective. We can use a `group by` clause to group names defined in a name-pair. e.g 'Mike' and 'Michael'. Then we count the number of distinct names in the result set . In the case when more than 1 distinct name exists, we delete the shorter one. Otherwise delete nothing as there is only 1 distinct name existing which we probably want to keep.

```
delete from Names where exists 
(
    select count(*) from 
    (select name from Names where (name='Michael' or name='Mike') group by name ) t 
    having count(*) >1
)
and name='Mike'
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I came to a similar solution myself, though I had to run a separate table to identify which names were 'related'. I then joined to that and create a group_concat using Order By so that each name with related names had the same group_concat and from there deleted the shorter one(s).